# Replace 0 with blank in dataframe Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I made the following code that takes out all of the zero's from my df. However when there is a number containing a zero it takes them out as well.

```
e.g.
3016.2     316.2
   0.235      .235


data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'] = data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'].str.replace('0', '')
```

Could you help me to figure out how I do an exact match of the cell that equals 0 and replace it with a blank value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data_usage_df = data_usage_df.astype(str)
data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'].replace(['0', '0.0'], '', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Simplest and cleanest solution I've found. For anyone not using `str` remove the quotes from around the 0 and 0.0.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need add `^` for matching start of string and `$` for end of string:

```
data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)']=data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'].str.replace('^0.0$', '')
```

Sample:

```
data_usage_df = pd.DataFrame({'Data Volume (MB)':[3016.2, 0.235, 1.4001, 0, 4.00]})

print (data_usage_df)
runfile('C:/Dropbox/work-joy/so/_t/test.py', wdir='C:/Dropbox/work-joy/so/_t')
   Data Volume (MB)
0         3016.2000
1            0.2350
2            1.4001
3            0.0000
4            4.0000

data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'] = data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'].astype(str)
data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)']=data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'].str.replace('^0.0$', '')

print (data_usage_df)
  Data Volume (MB)
0           3016.2
1            0.235
2           1.4001
3                 
4              4.0
```

Another solution is converting column [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and where is `0` give empty space:

```
data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'] = data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'].astype(str)

data_usage_df.ix[pd.to_numeric(data_usage_df['Data Volume (MB)'], errors='coerce') == 0, 
                                                              ['Data Volume (MB)']] = ''

print (data_usage_df)
  Data Volume (MB)
0           3016.2
1            0.235
2           1.4001
3                 
4              4.0
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help! I will accept the answer as soon as I can accept it, all the best